# How can you pass YUV frames from FFmpeg to OpenGL ES?

Tags: ios, opengl-es, ffmpeg, video-processing

Has anybody tried to use FFmpeg to decode a video frame, then display it in OpenGL ES in iOS 5.0?

I tried to modify the GLCameraRipple example from Apple, but I always get a -6683 error from `CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage()`.

Here is my decode code:

```
...

convertCtx = sws_getContext(codecCtx->width, codecCtx->height, codecCtx->pix_fmt, 
                            codecCtx->width, codecCtx->height, PIX_FMT_NV12, 
                            SWS_FAST_BILINEAR, NULL, NULL, NULL);

srcFrame = avcodec_alloc_frame();
dstFrame = avcodec_alloc_frame();
width = codecCtx->width;
height = codecCtx->height;

outputBufLength = avpicture_get_size(PIX_FMT_NV12, width, height);
outputBuf = malloc(outputBufLength);

avpicture_fill((AVPicture *)dstFrame, outputBuf, PIX_FMT_NV12, width, height);

...

avcodec_decode_video2(codecCtx, srcFrame, &gotFrame, pkt);

...

sws_scale(convertCtx, 
          (const uint8_t**)srcFrame->data, srcFrame->linesize, 
          0, codecCtx->height, 
          dstFrame->data, dstFrame->linesize);
```

Here is my code for display:

```
    CVPixelBufferRef pixelBuffer;
    CVPixelBufferCreateWithBytes(kCFAllocatorDefault, [videoDecoder width], [videoDecoder height], 
                                 kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8BiPlanarVideoRange, 
                                 dstFrame->data[0], dstFrame->linesize[0], 0, 0, 0, 
                                 &pixelBuffer);

    ...

CVReturn err;
int textureWidth = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(pixelBuffer);
int textureHeight = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(pixelBuffer);

if (!videoTextureCache)
{
    NSLog(@"No video Texture cache");
}

CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(pixelBuffer, 0);

// Y-plane
err = CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage(kCFAllocatorDefault, 
                                                   videoTextureCache, 
                                                   pixelBuffer, 
                                                   NULL, 
                                                   GL_TEXTURE_2D, 
                                                   GL_RED_EXT, 
                                                   textureWidth, 
                                                   textureHeight,
                                                   GL_RED_EXT, 
                                                   GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 
                                                   0, 
                                                   &lumaTexture);
if (err)
{
    NSLog(@"Error at CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage %d", err);
}

glBindTexture(CVOpenGLESTextureGetTarget(lumaTexture), CVOpenGLESTextureGetName(lumaTexture));
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

// UV-plane
err = CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage(kCFAllocatorDefault, 
                                                   videoTextureCache, 
                                                   pixelBuffer, 
                                                   NULL, 
                                                   GL_TEXTURE_2D, 
                                                   GL_RG_EXT, 
                                                   textureWidth / 2, 
                                                   textureHeight / 2,
                                                   GL_RG_EXT, 
                                                   GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 
                                                   1, 
                                                   &chromaTexture);
if (err)
{
    NSLog(@"Error at CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage %d", err);
}

glBindTexture(CVOpenGLESTextureGetTarget(chromaTexture), CVOpenGLESTextureGetName(chromaTexture));
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(pixelBuffer, 0);
```

I know that the code is not complete but it should be enough to understand my problem.

Could anybody please help me or show me some working example with this approach?

Comment: Hello, did you find a solution? I'm trying to the same thing...